# simplest animation causes high cpu usage and very high energy impact SpriteKit

Tags: animation, sprite-kit, rotation, cpu-usage, energy

Here is the simplest animation: a blackhole is rotating in the middle of the screen. These two lines of code increase cpu usage from 3% to 31% and energy impact from low to high (sometimes even very high):

```
    let actionLoop   = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.rotate(byAngle: CGFloat(360), duration: 1000))
    hole.run(actionLoop)
```

Is this normal? I've read more or less similar discussions but haven't find a clear answer. Here is the whole code and screens:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

// Basic for dynamic sizes step01
var width = CGFloat()
var height = CGFloat()

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    // Basic for dynamic sizes step02
    width = self.frame.size.width
    height = self.frame.size.height

    // test background color
    self.backgroundColor = .yellow

    // set blackhole
    let hole = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "blackhole")
    let startPosition = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    hole.size = CGSize(width: width/8, height: width/8)
    hole.position = CGPoint(x: startPosition.x, y: startPosition.y)


    let actionLoop   = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.rotate(byAngle: CGFloat(360), duration: 1000))
    hole.run(actionLoop)

    self.addChild(hole)



}
```

}

[image]
[image]

Update: And last but not least: it is not a simulator. I test it on the real device.

Comment: Is this in the simulator or on a device? CPU utilisation in the simulator can be ignored as it bears no resemblance to how the app will perform on a real device.

Comment: No, it not a simulator. It is a real device. I'll make an update now.

Comment: What else is going on with your ipad?  ipads behave differently than iphones, so you may have apps that are running on your ipad that will cause those numbers to jump

Comment: Ok, I'tested it on my iPhone right now. CPU usage: the same picture, 35% with animation and 3% without it. Interesting that energy impact is by zero in both cases! Thank you.

Comment: Checked by iPad once more. No, it does not depend on other apps. I have only this code running and the result is the same as before.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things your code does which might have impacted the efficiency.

First, `SKAction` rotation angles are calculated in radians (for the `360` degrees it should be `2*PI`, which is roughly `6.28`, not `360`). As it stands, your code does lots of calculations to 'over-rotate' the sprite, which is wasteful. A better statement would be:

```
SKAction.rotate(byAngle: CGFloat.pi*2, duration: 1000)
```

Second, before rotating the sprite, you scale it by half using the corresponding function, which is also a bit wasteful, since each time the rotation is calculated, the scaling is also re-calculated to produce an accurate result. I'd suggest to pre-render a scaled-down version of the sprite and use that instead to save calculation times and load.